# How to mimic Response.Write("string") in the WebPart

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, webforms, web-parts, html

I need to create a simplistic Sharepoint 2007 WebPart that outputs some string as part of HTML rendering. I would like this to be just the same as what `Response.Write(..)` does in the WebForms page. I am not seeing anything I can safely hook into in order to do that. Is it possible?

**Edit: Looking further at the WebPart I am finding this:**

```
   protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write();
        base.Render(writer);
    }
```

Should be good enough?

Comment: According to [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.render.aspx) it's better to override `RenderWebPart` instead of `Render` itself.

Comment: @SOException - I only have the RenderControl and Render for the overrides. I'm in 3.5.. Is that why?

Comment: Page.Response.Write()

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you're using the ASP.NET WebPart object and not the SharePoint WebPart object. Secondly, override the CreateChildControls method and use the LiteralControl class to output your string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx

You really shouldn't use the render methods if you can accomplish your task in CreateChildControls. When you can justify their use, you want to use RenderContents.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an ASP Label control in CreateChildControls and write the output there (generally what I do anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery. JQuery also has the SPServices plugin which allows for easier write and retrieval of data too.

Answer (score 0):

to create a simplistic SharePoint 2010 and 2013 WebPart that outputs some string as part of HTML rendering, today i use:

`Page.Response.Write()`

and this worked properly for me